# Why is set __cache_hash_code only available to std::__unordered_map?

Tags: c++, hash, c++11

I can see `std::__unordered_map` with `__cache_hash_code=true` has great runtime performance boost. But it is not available to `std::unordered_map`. Is `__cache_hash_code=true` deprecated?

Comment: `std::unordered_map` supports custom hash functors. If profiling shows that caching is desirable, you could implement that cache in a custom hash functor. That can be perfectly portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any identifier with double underscore (`__`) in the name is reserved by the implementation, so it's an implementation-specific piece of code that may or may not be supported with the same or different semantics in the future.

Unless profiling has revealed that the hashing is a significant bottleneck in your program, just use the standard container to help maintainability and portability.